# Spring Security Can Not Find Datasource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot MVC and Spring's `ServletRegistrationBean` gets called before my Datasource Configuration, which loads in `StandardContext`.

`WebSecurityConfig` always gets called first and therefore there is never a bean defined for the Autowired `prodDatasource`.

I tried everything from `@Order` to `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. I haven't been able to find a decent explanation. But I need to get a Bean created for the Datasource before it runs the WebSecurity

## Application (Using AutoConfigurations)

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("appInfo");
    }

}
```

## PrimaryDataSource

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "App.Models",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "prodEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
public class PrimaryDatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.prod")
    public DataSource prodDataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseFactory factory = new EmbeddedDatabaseFactory();
        factory.setDatabaseName("spring-social-quickstart");
        factory.setDatabaseType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);
        return factory.getDatabase();
    }
}
```

## WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(PrimaryDatasourceConfig.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource prodDataSource;

    SuperiorUserService jdbcDao;

.......

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(prodDataSource);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured a solution that seems to help.

Instead of using @Autowire in my Spring Security. I replaced them with `@Resource` and it appears to wait for my beans to be created first.